# How can I do a t-test on 2D data?

Tags: t-test, spatial, circular-statistics

How can I do a t-test on 2D data with latitude and longitude attributes? I have 2 clusters of similar coordinates but in different time, I want to do a t-test to see if they are statistically different. Can I do t-test? And if I can do, how can I apply t-test on 2 variables? Should I do a PCA or something?

Comment: Start by thinking about what null hypothesis you want to test. You need to get more specific than trying to find if two clusters are different.

Comment: If the centroid of the 2 clusters are significantly different?

Comment: Maybe Hotteling's T^2 test?

Comment: I don't think that PCA would be applicable in this case.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuzick%E2%80%93Edwards_test for one possibility.

Comment: @user5808583 Be careful; are you reasonably confident about independence or something quite close to it? (as would be assumed for something like a multivariate version of the t-test for example)